# Fontconfig default unavailable font selection, How is it defined in the XML configs? Couldn't locate in documentation

Tags: configuration, fonts, fontconfig

I've worked with Fontconfig previously, and understand how to do most of the common configurations.  All my aliases work as expected, and I'm almost completely finished. 
I'm trying to set the default unavailable font selection, and couldn't find anything helpful in any documentation.  Countless Google searches returned unrelated results.

To clarify what I'm attempting to configure, how can I specify which font is selected in this circumstance?

```
fc-match 'nonexistent font'
```

Comment: In what way is this related to Unix and/or Linux?

Comment: @Nils: ??? I'm not sure what you mean, after reading some meta answers, I was under the impression that components used with UNIX/Linux were on topic.  Fontconfig is a freedesktop.org project, and is part of the modern GNU/Linux desktop's TTF/OTF font stack.  It's an official package of many distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [fonts.conf man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html), you can set the `FC_DEBUG` environment variable to turn on a wide variety of additional messages from Fontconfig. For example, I tried

```
FC_DEBUG=$((1 + 2 + 4 + 4096)) fc-match "nonexistent font"
```

and I got a whole lot of messages that looked helpful. Of course there are even more flags you can add.